# Paperclip error when using :styles

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Profile model, which has attached file picture, using Paperclip. I am able to save the attachment picture normally, but when I use :styles for paperclip, I get the following error message:

> Profile picture
>   Paperclip::CommandNotFoundError

I do not know what's wrong or missing in my configurations. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that that you install ImageMagick package & rmagick gem.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to install ImageMagick. :styles are postprocessed by the ImageMagick command line tool.